# Symfony, event listener, checker. Как использовать несколько event listener для одного entity

Tags: события, symfony

Есть один entity и 2 event listener для него, когда обновляется поле, checker проверяет изменилось ли поле и дальше отрабатывает логика.
Проблема в том что listener блокирует второй listener, в итоге в втором listener не работает checker на изменение (говорит что поле не менялось) хотя в базе изменения есть.

```
public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getObject();
        if ($entity instance of Group) {
            $changedFields = $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
            $isChanged = $this->checker->isChanged($changedFields, ['teacher']);
            if ($isChanged) {
                $this->proceedTeacherChanges($entity);
            }
```

Comment: Если честно, не вижу смысла подписывать два слушателя на одно и то же событие для одной и той же сущности.

Comment: В моем случае я установил приоритет на лисенеры, и убрал flush у лисенера который отрабатывал первый, в таком случае он не очищает $changedFields и все работает нормально.

Comment: flush в listener-e вообще делать не рекомендуется, т.к. вы уже в нем и находитесь, документация советует вносить изменения через changesSet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При заходе в Listener, Doctrine пересчитывает все изменения, т.е. делает за вас это действие EntityManager->getUnitOfWork->computeChangesSet. Этот момент важен, т.к. под капотом, она перетирает массив с данными originalEntityData, на основе которого в основном и проводит все дальнейшие проверки, вроде isChanged и т.д.

В вашем случае, происходит следующее:

1. Doctrine поняла, что вы идете в Listener ее жизненного цикла и делает EntityManager->getUnitOfWork->computeChangesSet, в результате чего перетирает originalEntityData, тем самым фиксируя состояние ваших сущностей.
2. Заход в первый Listener.
3. Изменения есть, вы можете их проверить.
4. Doctrine аналогично понимает, что вы заходите в еще один Listener ее жизненного цикла и точно так же делает перерасчет изменений, но в первом слушателе, вы не внесли никаких изменений и получается, она проверяет зафиксированное, уже рассчитанное состояние с текущими сущностями, естественно diff-а у нее нет и изменений из предыдущего слушателя, она не увидит.

Это происходит как раз из-за оного массива данных originalEntityData, во время перерасчета она его обновляет до состояния сущностей и при повторном перерасчете, не увидит из-за этого изменений.

Зачастую в документации сказано, что не нужно самому перерассчитывать changesSet в Listener-ах, т.к. он считается автоматически, а в вашем случае получается, что вы заставляете Doctrine посчитать его два раза (что именно не рекомендуется) по средствам двойной подписки.